# ReactJS - Fill text input with object's info after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object `StudentItem` which is rendered in my main `App.js` component. Therefor, I have another component `EditStudentDetails` which is hidden and should be displayed after clicking on this object. I managed to make `EditStudentDetails` visible after clicking but I can't fill text areas with object's info. So my goal is to set value of these text areas with object's info after shooting an `onClick` event.

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state = {
        student: [
                {
                    Ime: "Martin",
                    Prezime: "Kostadinov",
                    Nasoka: "KNI",
                    Id: "161159"
                },

                {
                    Ime: "Darko",
                    Prezime: "Darkovski",
                    Nasoka: "KNI",
                    Id: "151234"
                }
        ],
            status: false
        }
        this.changeBoolean = this.changeBoolean.bind(this);
    }

    changeBoolean(){
        this.setState({status: true})
    }

  render() {

        let tmp;
        if(this.state.status){
            tmp = (<div>
                <EditStudentDetails/>
            </div>);
        }

    return (
       <div className="App">
            <div>
                <StudentItem student={this.state.student[0]} changeBoolean={this.changeBoolean}/>
            </div>
           <div>
               <StudentItem student={this.state.student[1]} changeBoolean={this.changeBoolean}/>
           </div>
           {tmp}
       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class StudentItem extends React.Component{

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <li onClick={this.props.changeBoolean}>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                    {this.props.student.Ime}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                    {this.props.student.Prezime}
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class EditStudentDetails extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type={"text"} id={"txt1"}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type={"text"} id={"txt2"}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type={"text"} id={"txt3"}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type={"text"} id={"txt4"}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type={"submit"}>Click</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so I understand, is your intent to pass in the student details as props to `EditStudentDetails`?

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces I think your question is actually the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the selected student as a prop to `EditStudentDetails` similarly to how you pass a student object to `StudentItem`. This means you need a way to keep track of which student was selected rather than just a boolean `status`.

You might also consider factoring out the list of `StudentItem`s as a component, perhaps called `StudentList`. Then `App` should decide whether to render `EditStudentDetails` or `StudentList` based on its state.

You will also need a way to display an entire list of `StudentItem`s of unknown length instead of just two. You can do this with the `map()` function.